# finds the indexs of the matching Records in jasonstore?

Tags: extjs

`find()` finds the index of the first matching Record in this store by a specific field value.

Is there a method to get all the indexes of the matching records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use each and build your own collection:

```
var indexes = [];
store.each(function(rec, index) {
    if (rec.get('foo') {
        indexes.push(index);
    }
});
```